# Using Grails HSQLDB in an external application

Tags: java, database, grails, hsqldb

Is it possible to write an external application that will utilize Grail's HSQLDB instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppoose you mean the external application will connect to the HSQLDB database used by Grails. In this case you should set up HSQLDB as a Server instance and change the Grails connection URL to connect to the server. Other external applications can now connect to the server. The URL to connect to an HSQLDB Server instance is in the form "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql:server_address"